# C# Locking an object that is reassigned in lock block

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have this code in a class:

```
private static MyObject _locker = new MyObject();

...

lock (_locker)
{
     ...
     _locker = new MyObject();
     ...
}
```

Will it keep the lock on _locker ?

Comment: That seems like a bad idea, why would you do that?

Comment: You should mark the `_locker` object with the `readonly` keyword.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it will not. From the C# specification (emphasis is mine):

> A lock statement of the form `lock (x)
>   ...` where x is an expression of a
>   reference-type, is precisely
>   equivalent to
>
> ```
> System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(x);
> try {
>   ...
> }
> finally {
>   System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(x);
> }
> ```
>
> **except that x is only evaluated once**.

Since `x` is not reevaluated the lock will be released.

Comment: lock keyword is syntactical sugar. If you were coding in managed c++ with .net framework 1.1, you would have had to lock the way João has specified.

Comment: Right on the spot Joao. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this.  Consider using a separate object entirely to hold the state of the lock, not necessarily the object you want to protect in the lock statement.  I often write code (ok, not often) like this:

```
private static readonly object _locker = new object();
private static MyObject _object;
...

lock (_locker)
{
     ...
     _object = new MyObject();
     ...
}
```

It involves a completely different sort of program flow than what you're looking at.  lock() defines a critical section in the code -- you don't use it as an all-purpose thread safety mechanism for any type of object (which is what I think your intent is in your code?)

Comment: And declare `_locker` as `readonly` so that it can't be accidentally re-assigned.

Comment: Great idea.  Edited accordingly.

Comment: I wish I could create a state object without complicating things.

Answer (score 2):

I assume it will keep the lock on the `MyObject` instance that was set to `_locker` when `lock` has been called, i.e. it will keep the lock on the original instance of `_locker`, not on the newly created `MyObject` instance. In the following code, the lock will be kept on `MyObject("OriginalInstance")` when the `lock` is called for the first time. When it is called the second time, it will lock on `MyObject("NewInstance")`.

```
private static MyObject _locker = new MyObject("OriginalInstance");

...

lock (_locker)
{
    ...
    _locker = new MyObject("NewInstance");
    ...
}
```

Therefore, the next thread may enter the critical section without problems because the new instance is not locked.

Anyway, doing stuff like this is generally **considered bad practice**. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) for some advices on how to use `lock`.

Comment: Well.. it is a bad practice indeed. I need to find ways to prevent the reinstanciation from happening.

Comment: Declare the variable as `readonly`, as already stated by others here.