# Need to deploy single threaded in memory store

Tags: c#, asp.net, thread-safety

Using Asp.Net 4/c#

I want to store a list of items in memory (I use the term list generically) rather than list. I need to maintain a last used date for items in the list.

Effictively I need to lock, find the earliest date, update it and unlock and return the record.

As a relative newbie, I have a couple of questions:

- What is the best way to store the data;
- Is there a documented    locking pattern I can use to ensure thread
  safety.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874317/thread-safe-listt-property

Comment: The thread does not answer the question asked. It demontrates a lockable list, and does not answer the first part of the question asked here.

Comment: "the best way ..." question requires your definition of "better". Otherwise it deserves to be closed. At very least explain why data structure you are using currently (which one?) does not suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description what you want is a queue & a locking mechanism around that queue. The queue is a first in first out container, which means objects will be dequeued in the order they are enqueued, guaranteeing your update order constraint. As for the synchronization constraint, because you want to do the work inside of the lock, you'll need a lock at a higher level than your queue. Something like this should do the trick but needs to be used the correct way, as a LockingDequeu() without dispose will permanently lock the queue.

```
public class MyQueue<T>
{
    private readonly Queue<T> internalQueue = new Queue<T>();
    private readonly object queueLocker = new object();

    public Enqueue(T data)
    {
        internalQueue(data);
    }

    public IDisposable LockingDequeue(out T data)
    {
        var queueLock = new QueueLock(queueLocker);
        data = internalQueue.Dequeue();
        return queueLock;
    }

    private class QueueLock :IDisposable
    {
        private readonly object lockObject;

        public QueueLock(object lockObject)
        {
            this.lockObject = lockObject;
            Monitor.Enter(lockObject);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Understand that the `LockingDequeue` call needs to be used within a using block. But the calling syntaxt would look like this:

```
var myQueue = new MyQueue<object>();
object obj;
using(myQueue.LockingDequeue(out obj))
{
    //update date
    //do some work
    myQueue.Enqueue(obj);
}
```