# Is this usage of List<T> thread safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, parallel.for

I have C# .NET 4 code which is adding to a `List<string>` inside a `Parallel.For`.
I can't find a definite answer to if this is thread-safe or not.
If it is unsafe what are the alternatives?

```
    static List<int> Calculate(List<string[]> numbers)
    {
           List<int> sums = new List<int>();

         
            Parallel.ForEach(numbers,
            (nums) =>
            {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
                     sum += Convert.ToInt32( nums[i]);

                // is this thread safe or not???
                sums.Add(sum);
            });

            sums.Sort();
            return sums;
    }
```

Comment: You can find a definite answer by **reading the documentation**, specifically the section labeled "Thread Safety". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thread-safe List<T> property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874317/thread-safe-listt-property)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's not thread-safe. You might be looking for the [`ConcurrentBag<T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx), a thread-safe unordered collection.  Some more info and other thread-safe collections are available at [MSDN's Thread-Safe Collections documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx).  E.g.

```
static List<int> Calculate(List<string[]> numbers)
{
       var sums = new ConcurrentBag<int>();


        Parallel.ForEach(numbers,
        (nums) =>
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
                 sum += Convert.ToInt32( nums[i]);

            sums.Add(sum);
        });

        var sorted = sums.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
        return sorted;
}
```

Comment: I removed both my comment and my answer, because I thought `sums` and `nums` is the same list. That is not the case, making all my argumentation moot. You are of course correct that the concurrent bag helps here.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid thread-safety issues (and gain on performance) by converting your method into a PLINQ operation:

```
static List<int> Calculate(List<string[]> numbers)
{
    return numbers.AsParallel()
                  .Select(nums => nums.Sum(Convert.ToInt32))
                  .OrderBy(i => i)
                  .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No it's not.

> A List can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the
>   collection is not modified. Enumerating through a collection is
>   intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an
>   enumeration contends with one or more write accesses, the only way to
>   ensure thread safety is to lock the collection during the entire
>   enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple
>   threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own
>   synchronization.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)