# Is ArrayList/List a thread safe collection? If not how would you make it thread safe?

Tags: c#

Is ArrayList/List a thread safe collection? If not how would you make it thread safe?

Comment: We would make it for you?

Comment: This is an honest question, and in all fairness, people should explain why they leave down votes.

Answer (score 6):

ArrayList/List is not a thread safe collection. We can make ArrayList a thread safe like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
public class SamplesArrayList  
{
   public static void Main()  
   {      
      // Creates and initializes a new ArrayList. It is thread safe ArrayList
      ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
      myAL.Add( "The" );
      myAL.Add( "quick" );
      myAL.Add( "brown" );
      myAL.Add( "fox" );

      // Creates a synchronized wrapper around the ArrayList.
      ArrayList mySyncdAL = ArrayList.Synchronized(myAL);

      // Displays the sychronization status of both ArrayLists.
      Console.WriteLine( "myAL is {0}.", myAL.IsSynchronized ? "synchronized" : "not synchronized" );
      Console.WriteLine( "mySyncdAL is {0}.", mySyncdAL.IsSynchronized ? "synchronized" : "not synchronized" );

   }
}
```

This code produces the following output.

myAL is not synchronized.
mySyncdAL is synchronized.

Comment: You are sure you want to use a .Net 1.0 API ArrayList, I thought no-one use this old DS any more. Concurrent namespace has much better options.

Comment: Right you need to use latest version of .NET Framework. because everyone is updated with latest version .NET Framework. Or at least users have updated with .Net Framework 3.5/4/4.5.1.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - what are the better options? This is one of the only readable examples of using a thread safe collection I've been able to find.

Answer (score 1):

No, according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread
>   safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

You should use concurrent collections ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx)).

**BlockingCollection** Provides bounding and blocking functionality for any type that implements IProducerConsumerCollection.

**ConcurrentDictionary**
Thread-safe implementation of a dictionary of key-value pairs

**ConcurrentQueue**
Thread-safe implementation of a FIFO (first-in, first-out) queue.

**ConcurrentStack**
Thread-safe implementation of a LIFO (last-in, first-out) stack.

**ConcurrentBag**
Thread-safe implementation of an unordered collection of elements.

**IProducerConsumerCollection**
The interface that a type must implement to be used in a BlockingCollection.

Comment: Can't get it, you mean static types are thread safe, in my view they are not for sure or I am misreading your post

Comment: @MrinalKamboj it means that all static method / members of class are thread safe.

Comment: I doubt, you mean a static List<T> in a class is thread safe ? static methods have nothing to do with the thread safety it is the static members which would matter. Try modifying static List<T> from multiple threads

Comment: @MrinalKamboj not a static instance. I mean static method of class:  http://www.completecsharptutorial.com/basic/staticmethod-variables.php. `Add` method is not static, so it is not thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

No, neither of them is.

The simplest way to make it thread-safe is to `lock` *all* the access to the underlying collections (read *and* write). Of course, depending on your actual *problem*, it might simply be better to use a different collection, one that is thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my implementation using reader Writer lock, in case you really need one, but you would be better off  using the Cocurrent APIs, they are guaranteed by MS

[Creating Thread Safe List using Reader Writer Lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681321/creating-thread-safe-list-using-reader-writer-lock)

Comment: As in the comments of my implementation you would need an extra check in the implementations that fetch via index to ensure that index actually exist or they would be Null

Answer (score 0):

No

here is a list of [Thread Safe Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SyncRoot property of the collection to make it thread safe 
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.syncroot(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
ICollection myCollection = someCollection;
lock(myCollection.SyncRoot)
{
    foreach (object item in myCollection)
    {
        // Insert your code here.
    }
}
```