# Concurrent access of List<T> in C#

Tags: c#, concurrency, thread-safety

If one thread is adding an object in a `List<T>` in C# and other thread is modifying an attribute of an object in the list, is there any possibility of conflict, or .NET has implemented mechanism in the `List<T>` that avoids such conflicting situation to happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thread-safe List<T> property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874317/thread-safe-listt-property)

Comment: Despite what the answers below say, you can safely take a reference to an object stored in the list, and change its properties without changes to the list affecting the object itself. If you manipulate the same object from multiple threads, however, you need to ensure that the object is thread-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipulating objects referenced from the list in concurrent threads can cause conflicts in objects regarding state of the object. Manipulating items in the list can cause conflicts in collections, as many things happen in background, like reallocating buffers or copying elements when adding new items. You have to take care of both. For lists targeting .NET 4 you could use the [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent) namespace.

Answer (score 4):

C# Lists are not thread-safe.

.NET Framework 4 introduces thread-safe collections in the [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) namespace.

You could use `ConcurrentBag<T>` instead of a `List<T>`

Answer (score 1):

Typically there is no built-in protection. There are collections that are thread-safe (see for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.7.2) and the original collections had a Synchronized property that could be used, but by default collections are not thread safe.