# How can I work with threadsafe Lists in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

So, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874317/thread-safe-listt-property) question asks how to threadsave lists. To sum it up, instead of using

```
List<int[]> listName = new List<int[]>();

//you use:

SynchronizedCollection<int[]> listName = new SynchronizedCollection<int[]>();
```

But my problem is, that if I use:

```
int[] returnArray = new int[listName[0].Length];
```

I can't access those elements with indexing. How can I access them then? Is there not a way to make lists threadsafe without loosing any functionality?

Maybe I can work with limited functionality, I only need 4 things: reading the lowest and the highest elements (only those), deleting listName[0] and adding something on top. So I don't need any of the elements in the middle actually. But there are 2 threads and depending on what the thread did it will either add a new one on top and take it or delete the lowest one and take the new lowest one.

I can't use queues or stacks because of this, so I am all out of ideas.

Now the question is, is there something that fills those requirements?

Comment: It doesn't sound like the problem is which collection type to use, although it's a little bit unclear. This might get easier if you look at how to control access to the collection to make sure that the simultaneous modifications you're concerned about can't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) to access an object from multiple threads

Comment: Do you mean lock it in order to keep it from being edited by multiple threads?

Comment: I would start with this. If you start with some locks just to ensure that the simultaneous access you're concerned about can't happen then it might be a lot easier than trying to find a specific collection type. If you get some version of it that works - even if it doesn't look optimal - then you've got a starting point to make changes or show someone what problems it solves. (Or that solution might just be good enough as-is.)

Comment: @bv_Martn, `SynchronizedCollection` uses the `lock` underneath so there is no significant difference of using `lock` or `SynchronizedCollection` from the final result perspective.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov well yes but then I can not use indices

Comment: @bv_Martn, why cannot you use the indices with lock ? I meant that you can effectively substitute `SynchronizedCollection` which `lock`.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov oh yes, you're right. that is how i solved i