# How to wait for the result while controller is making parallel call

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to find account details from DB (GetAccountDetailAsync) for an array of accounts and would like to run in parallel to make it faster.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAccountsAsync(IEnumerable<int> accountIds)
{

    var resultAccounts = new List<AccountDetail>();

    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(accountIds, new ParallelOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 
        }, async accountId =>
        {
            var response = await GetAccountDetailAsync(accountId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            resultAccounts.AddRange(response);

        });
    });

    task.Wait();

    return Ok(resultAccounts);

}
```

But instead of getting the result I am getting though I've got task.Wait.
Not sure why task.Wait is not being blocked.

**"An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending."**

Comment: Are you sure `task.Wait()` is not blocking execution until `task` completes its execution?

Comment: Yeah that's what I have noticed

Comment: Remove the `task` altogether (and `Task.Run` and `Wait`) and just call `Parallel.ForEach` directly. And remove the `async` inside the `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: Yeah why are you even creating that task?

Comment: Note your code isn't safe though since `List` is not thread-safe - and you appear to be calling `AddRange` from multiple threads. You really should use `accountIds.AsParallel().StuffHere().ToList()`.

Comment: If I will just run Parallel.Each it returns no account as while the Parallel is being invoked it goes to the next.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nesting await in Parallel.ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach)

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't really support `async` calls you need to use [TPL dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11565317/542251)

Comment: Or use a [standard async `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11565531/542251) depending on if you really, really need parallel or async processing. Either way this is a dupe

Comment: @mjwills I totally agree with you. The list is not thread safe. But how is the syntax as I am trying to return a list to the controller. I am lost here

Comment: and here's a [thread safe list (type) data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5874347/542251)

Comment: One of the below answers should get you started @Bulu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parallel.ForEach` doesn't work with `async` actions, but you could start all tasks and then wait for them all to complete using `Task.WhenAll`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAccountsAsync(IEnumerable<int> accountIds)
{
    Task<List<AccountDetail>>[] tasks = accountIds.Select(accountId => GetAccountDetailAsync(accountId)).ToArray();
    List<AccountDetail>[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return Ok(results.SelectMany(x => x).ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have or can easily get a method `GetAccountDetail` without the async part, this would be the easiest way:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAccountsAsync(IEnumerable<int> accountIds)
{
   var resultList = accountIds.AsParallel()
                              .WithDegreeOfParallelism(5)
                              .Select(GetAccountDetail)
                              .ToList();
   return Ok(resultList);
}
```

Comment: "Without the async part", you might as well use `Parallel.ForEach` without creating any tasks.

Comment: @mm8 Yes, but then they need to figure out concurrency and locking the result container themselves.

Comment: True, the `List<AccountDetail>` should either be replaced by a `ConcurrentBag<AccountDetail>` or you need to synchronize the access to it.