# How to create an extension method overshadowing the regular LINQ extensions?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, .net-8.0

I have the following setup, which works as supposed to.

```
public Thing[] GetThings(Guid id)
  => Context.Things
    .Include(a => a.Members)
    .Where(a => ...).ToArray()
    .SelectArr(a => (Stuff)a with { Related = a.Members.Any(...) });
```

The special method `SelectArr` is an extension method because I'm making extensive usage of arrays and making everything an array instead of list or enumerable got tedious.

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
  public static T2[] SelectArr<T1, T2>(
    this IEnumerable<T1> self, Func<T1, T2> lambda)
    => self.Select(lambda).ToArray();
}
```

Then, I tried to overload (shadow, hide etc.) the conventional `Select` and changed the syntax accordingly. However, switching to it as below wouldn't work.

```
public Thing[] GetThings(Guid id) => ...
    .Select(a => (Stuff)a with { Related = a.Members.Any(...) });

public static T2[] Select<T1, T2>(
  this IEnumerable<T1> self, Func<T1, T2> lambda) => ...;
```

Apparently, [CS8849](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/expression-tree-restrictions), an expression tree may not contain a `with`-expression. I'm not really sure why nor how to del with it.

I've seen very few relevant hits (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59947367/1525840), not really suggesting an extension method). Most of the results are about how to create an extension method in a general sense, which I already have working. I also found [this](https://robvolk4.rssing.com/chan-12580346/article2.html) that creates a whole new object without `with`. But I'm trying to apply records (hence `with`) together with the implicit operator (hence the magical cast that, in fact, is a creation in the source object where I can't pass an extra argument).

The best guest I have at the moment is that I don't get into my extension method but, rather, into the conventional one. I can't figure out how to overload/override/new it replacing it with my version. I'm not even sure anymore if I should poke at the projection (i.e. `Select(...)`) or the filtration (i.e. `Where(...)`).

I'm also considering skipping the implicit operator and actually creating the new record instance during the projection but that's a bit like giving up.

```
public static implicit operator Stuff(Thing self) 
  => new(...);
```

**edit**

Based on the suggested explanation, I restructured the extension method to target `IQueryable` like this.

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
  //public static T2[] Select<T1, T2>(
  // this IEnumerable<T1> self, Func<T1, T2> lambda)
  // => self.Select(lambda).ToArray();

  public static T2[] Select<T1, T2>(
    this IQueryable<T1> self, Func<T1, T2> lambda)
      => self.AsEnumerable().Select(lambda).ToArray();
}
```

This produces the error in the invoking method regarding ambiguity. Most importantly, though, it doesn't resolves my main problem, because I'd like to extend on the enumerables not the queryables.

Comment: CS8849 suggests that the call is still being resolved to the `Select` in `System.Linq`, not the `Select` you declared. Where did you declare your own `Select`? If you declare it in the same namespace as `GetThings`, it should work as expected. Did you declare it in somewhere else?

Comment: @Sweeper My extension method is placed in namespace `Api.Utils.Extensions`, while the invoking method in namespace `Api.Services.Implementations`. Are you saying that they must reside in the same namespace **precisely** or that they should be in the same "root", i.e. `Api.blablabla`? It would be a terrible deterioration of the structure if I placed my services' implementations in the same namespace as the utilities' extensions.

Comment: See the duplicate target for how extension method resolution works. Your own `Select` should be in the same namespace as, or a parent namespace of, where `GetThings` is declared. If you don't want to change the structure, I'd suggest just keep the `SelectArr` name.

Comment: @Sweeper I checked it out. Since the queryable is the most derived, that's the one it targets. However, I simply want to shadow **all** kinds of Select so they produce an array. (In my application, it's the strategy to return arrays everywhere. I'll probably go with `SelectArr(...)` but I can't shake of the sensation that we're giving in, capitulating to the machine. It's pragmatic. But still...   :)

Comment: Because you're making extensive usage of arrays do `this T1[] self` instead of `this IEnumerable<T1> self`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov That will reoslve half of my problem - the need to convert to an array after each `Select(...)`, which is great. However, the other part of my intention is to make (it look like) the current `Select(...)`, `Where(...)` etc. to give me an array so I don't have to type that in the code of my main business logic. (Yes, I understand I'll still do that inside the extension method. The point is to move it out of the main logic flow.)