# Exception in the thread-safe list

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core

After reading a couple of notes that it's better not to lock the whole `foreach` block, decided to always return a cloned instance of the collection from the enumerator. This is the code that I'm currently using.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5874474/437393

Then, some code from another thread calls `collection.ElementAtOrDefault(collection.Count - 1)` and `Clone` method inside of my collection breaks with exception below. **Why and how to make it right?**

`Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length`

**Collection**

```
private static readonly object _indexLock = new object();

...

public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
  return Clone().GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
  return Clone().GetEnumerator();
}

public List<T> Clone()
{
  var copy = new List<T>(_items.Count);

  lock (_indexLock)
  {
    copy = _items.ToList();
    //_items.ForEach(o => copy.Add(o));
  }

  return copy;
}
```

Comment: Do you use the `_indexLock` to protect all access to the `_items` list from everywhere?

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias Yes, if I protect `_items` with lock everywhere, everything works fine. Meanwhile, the whole point of this experiment is to use a copy of the collection instead of locking it.

Comment: Could you update your question by providing a minimal example that reproduces this error?

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing _items.Count outside the lock, either remove the call to _items.Count or move it inside the lock:

```
var copy = new List<T>(_items.Count);
```

Comment: `Count` is a property, not a method. It doesn't cause enumeration. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs Also, I tried moving it inside, still was getting the same intermittent error. Also, tried to do `return _items.ToList()` without variables and memory allocation, so there was only one line inside `lock`. No changes.