# Concurrently changing List<T> from multiple async functions in C#

Tags: c#, async-await, concurrency, thread-safety

So, I have a use case where I want to pass a list to async functions working concurrently. Each function will append their result to the list passed. So, my doubt is will this cause any concurrency problem with list?

```
var errors = new List<Error>();

var awaitedTasks = new List<Task>();
awaitedTasks.Add(funcA(list));
awaitedTasks.Add(funcB(list));
awaitedTasks.Add(funcC(list));
awaitedTasks.Add(funcD(list));

await Task.WhenAll(awaitedTasks);
```

Comment: @Anuj Perhaps you could change from using `List<T>` to some of the built in concurrent types: [thread-safe-listt-property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874317/thread-safe-listt-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, it depends. There are details around things like task schedulers which *could* cause your functions to make changes to the list in parallel.

It's usually best to use a *functional* paradigm, where you expect the methods to *return* their values instead of appending them to the list you provide. Then the calling function can collect them into results.

```
var awaitedTasks = new List<Task>();
awaitedTasks.Add(funcA());
awaitedTasks.Add(funcB());
awaitedTasks.Add(funcC());
awaitedTasks.Add(funcD());

var list = await Task.WhenAll(awaitedTasks);
```

If you need the functions' progress to be reported as the items are completed rather than after all of them are done, you can add continuations to the function calls with appropriate semaphores in place.

```
var reportingTasks = awaitedTasks.Select(async result => {
    // code that updates `list` in a thread-safe way
    // (or otherwise reports results)
}).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(reportingTasks);
```

That way, the code to manage that complexity is all in one place and not spread throughout your various async functions.

Answer (score 0):

The `List<T>` class [is not thread-safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1#thread-safety), meaning that if more than one threads are allowed to interact with it concurrently, the behavior of your program becomes undefined. The effects can be data corruption, lost updates, random exceptions, basically anything. So unless you are absolutely sure that it's impossible for two threads to interact with the list concurrently, your coding pattern is flawed.